# Powershell - Display cleanup (get-filehash results in a .txt file)

Tags: powershell

This is a cleanup/display kind of question. My little powershell script takes any .exe files in a folder, finds multiple hash values for each entry, and outputs it to a .txt file. My issue is the format in the file. Here is the loop I'm using to generate those results.

```
$output = foreach($file in $table){
  $File.Name
  get-filehash -path $file.FullName
  get-filehash -path $file.FullName -Algorithm SHA1
  get-filehash -path $file.FullName -Algorithm MD5
}
$output | Out-File C:\filepath\file.txt
```

The ouput looks something like this:

```
Name.exe

Algorithm           Hash           Path
----------          ----           -----
SHA256              Value           C:\Path\Name.exe
SHA1                Value           C:\Path\Name.exe
MD5                 Value           C:\Path\Name.exe
NextFile.exe
SHA256              Value           C:\Path\NextFile.exe
SHA1                Value           C:\Path\NextFile.exe
MD5                 Value           C:\Path\NextFile.exe
```

Is there a way to clean this up in the foreach loop? I know its picky, but is there a way to either move the first file's name below the column names or to create a break and have new column names after each file's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discard the separate file name output, pipe to `Format-Table` and use the `-GroupBy` parameter to group the tables on the file path:

```
$output = foreach($file in $table){
  Get-FileHash -Path $file.FullName
  Get-FileHash -Path $file.FullName -Algorithm SHA1
  Get-FileHash -Path $file.FullName -Algorithm MD5
}

$output |Format-Table -GroupBy Path |Out-File C:\filepath\file.txt
```

And your output will now be grouped into separate tables per consecutive file path:

```
   Path: C:\path\to\Name.exe

Algorithm       Hash       Path
---------       ----       ----
SHA256          Value      C:\path\to\Name.exe
SHA1            Value      C:\path\to\Name.exe
MD5             Value      C:\path\to\Name.exe


   Path: C:\path\to\NextFile.exe

Algorithm       Hash       Path
---------       ----       ----
SHA256          Value      C:\path\to\NextFile.exe
SHA1            Value      C:\path\to\NextFile.exe
MD5             Value      C:\path\to\NextFile.exe
```

---

`-GroupBy` supports calculated property expressoins, so if you need only the `Name` of the file, that's feasible as well:

```
$output |Format-Table -GroupBy @{Name='Name';Expression={[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_.Path)}} |Out-File C:\filepath\file.txt
```

... resulting in something like this:

```
   Name: Name.exe

Algorithm       Hash       Path
---------       ----       ----
SHA256          Value      C:\path\to\Name.exe
SHA1            Value      C:\path\to\Name.exe
MD5             Value      C:\path\to\Name.exe


   Name: NextFile.exe

Algorithm       Hash       Path
---------       ----       ----
SHA256          Value      C:\path\to\NextFile.exe
SHA1            Value      C:\path\to\NextFile.exe
MD5             Value      C:\path\to\NextFile.exe
```